# In "Romeo and Juliet" by William Shakespeare, does "ay" mean "yes" or "always"?

Tags: shakespeare

> And since that time it is eleven years,
>   For then she could stand alone. Nay, by the rood,
>   She could have run and waddled all about,
>   For even the day before, she broke her brow.
>   And then my husband—God be with his soul!
>   He was a merry man—took up the child.
>   “Yea,” quoth he, “Dost thou fall upon thy face?
>   Thou wilt fall backward when thou hast more wit,
>   Wilt thou not, Jule?” and, by my holy dame,
>   The pretty wretch left crying and said “**ay**.”

The dictionary entry that comes *first* has this to say about "ay":

[ey]

adverb, Archaic.

ever; always.

The one that says it is a variant of "aye" is *third* on the list.

[Here's the dictionary entry](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ay?s=t)

Both meanings fit perfectly; the former ("always") is a dash more comical.

Which is it?

Comment: She was *crying*, so it's always possible she was using ***Ay!*** (sometimes repeated, and spelt ***Ai-ai-ai!***) in the sense given by the full OED as ***Alas! Ah me!** — an ejaculation of regret, sorrow, pity.* But it's all a matter of opinion and Lit Crit interpretation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, but she *left crying*.

Comment: She brightened up.

Comment: @StoneyB: Literary Studies degree or not, I'm not daft enough to argue with *you* of all people about the precise meaning of a line in Shakespeare! My substantive point (clearly bolstered by *Both meanings fit perfectly* in the OP) is that it's essentially a matter of Lit Crit / Interpretation. Obviously Ricky here *doesn't* agree that such interpretation is Off Topic for ELU, but that's my position.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to [literature.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [No Fear Shakespeare  → Romeo and Juliet  → Act 1, Scene 3, Page 3](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/romeojuliet/page_42.html)

> “Yes,” said my husband, “Did you fall on your face? You’ll fall
>   backward when you grow up, won’t you, Jule?” And she stopped crying
>   and said, “Yes.”

Comment: I'm upvoting, but No Fear Shakespeare is no Gospel.

Comment: I know.  My Riverside Shakespeare is at home.

Comment: That is a poor gloss: it ruins the joke. I'd say not a reliable source for the meaning of the original.

Comment: @MetaEd I finally got a look at my Riverside Shakspeare and it does not have a footnote for "Ay". Is your problem the fact that I essentially cited Sparknotes? While I understand your prejudice against the source remember that these notes are written by serious experts.

Comment: It's actually to do with how they treated the rest of the quoted passage.

Comment: The NFS original source text doesn't match Riverside even though the relevant lines are close. The Riverside 'Notes on the text' starts with, "Romeo and Juliet presents a complicated textual problem." Ay. :-)